# show stacked legends in a grouped column highcharts- RecatJs highcharts

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

I have an example taken from highcharts: this question is very similar to [Highcharts: legend of stacked chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480981/highcharts-legend-of-stacked-chart)
however I havent found the answer I'm looking there.
what I'm looking is something is to group the stack legends like shown below for every name legend it belongs.

[image]

in my case I want to have following structure in the legend

```
Male:
 Joe
 JOhn
Female:
 Janet
 Jane
```

is that possible?

I also tried : http://jsfiddle.net/7sgdbezh/
however since I'd be having multiple legends I dont want to clutter the chart with too many redundant stack name values.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'female'
        }, {
            name: 'Janet',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'female'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to use the Highchart class instead of using the JS directly. There might be some differences. e.g:- Highcharts.chart('container', { });

Comment: @SarunUK: this is not my appl, this is just an example I took from source, in my actaully app, I dont use either of that. I dont think that is the issue at all.. :(

Comment: provide more info related to your use case. I will try to help :)

Comment: @SarunUK: so this is the example I'm playing with, since my app is too heavy to create a fiddle from, I'm using https://jsfiddle.net/itsjustcarlos/uz1t1fbu/1/ as my POC. As you can see there are stacked labels listed: "seconds streets sis" however they are repeated for every stack , i.e stack:["home", "vavcation","work" ]. I want to visually group these legends into categories under stack name, i.e ```home: seconds, streets, sis``` ==>image as shown above